# how to replace email id text before @ with * in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resetting password in react Js. I need to display that email is sent to their email Id. I don't want to display their whole email instead I want to replace some characters with *.
For example, someone has an email testing@gmail.com so I want to replace some random character with * ie tes***g@gmail.com.
How could I do that in javascript??
My code:

```
let a = testing@gmail.com
let c = a.split('@');
let b = c[0].slice(0,-3)+'***'+'@'+c[1];
```

but it is not efficient way.How to do efficiently??

suppose if i have test@gmail.com then it should display t**t@gmail.com and if any@gmail.com it should be like a*y@gmail.com.

Comment: *"but it is not efficient way."* Why not?

Comment: i want to slice from second last not from last one

Comment: [How to slice string from the end in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308976/how-to-slice-string-from-the-end-in-javascript)

Comment: Try regex replace

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371339/how-to-retrieve-name-from-email-address

Comment: i have a issue of name..it fines for longer name.how do i set this pattern in smaller one.I want to do dynamically

Comment: Do you know which specific indexes/characters to be replaced?

Comment: I suggest you give some examples of input and expected output.  When you say you have an issue for short names you don't tell us what you want to happen.  Update the question with a few email address examples and what you want to get back.

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```js
 var input = "testing@gmail.com";

function callme(){
    var a = input.split("@"); 
    var b = a[0];
    var newstr = "";
    for(var i in b){
     if(i>2 && i<b.length-1)newstr += "*";
     else newstr += b[i];
    }
    console.log(newstr +"@"+ a[1]);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="callme()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Wait till the OP clarifies what they want.  This won't obfuscate any email addresses with the name part < 4 characters long.

Comment: ya you are right. I wrote this code as per output! :)

Comment: jQuery is included because…?

Answer (score 2):

You've got the start: split into parts and apply an algorithm to the first part to replace some characters, then join the bits again.

The following replaces part of the first part based on a formula that always leaves the last character and replaces at least one of the leading characters. It replaces more of the leading characters as the string gets longer.

Tweak the multipliers that generate the *startIndex* and *endIndex* values to replace more or fewer characters.

```js
function mungeEmailAddress(s) {
  var i = s.indexOf('@');
  var startIndex = i * .2 | 0;
  var endIndex   = i * .9 | 0;
  return s.slice(0, startIndex) +
         s.slice(startIndex, endIndex).replace(/./g, '*') +
         s.slice(endIndex);
}

// Testing...
for (var s='', t = '@foo.com', i=97; i<110; i++) {
  s += String.fromCharCode(i);
  console.log(s + t + ' => ' + mungeEmailAddress(s + t));
}
```